# Two classes create instances of each other

Tags: vb.net

I have a web form that uses two classes - A and B. Class A contains all the functions I need to create CSV and Excel reports. Class B is all process-specific code.

The nature of the overall process forces me to have Class A call a method contained in Class B. The problem with that - which I just discovered - is Class A needs to create an instance of Class B to do this and Class B already creates an instance of Class A, causing an infinite loop.

What would be the proper way for me to handle this? If I could just be pointed in the right direction as far as methodology goes, I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Couldn't you convert one of them to an interface (maybe Class A) and just implement that in the other class?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You could have a constructor with a boolean and only instantiate class A if it's true

Comment: Not sure what your classes do. But instead of having Class B instantiate Class A, you should have a function in Class A called InitializeFromClassB(...) and pass an instance of class b.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry about that. I've always done that so I guess it's time to stop! Thank you to the rest of you for the suggestions! I will go through them when I'm in front of my code tomorrow and report back.

Comment: @tim: you didn't do that too much. I just ran through your questions, and found only three cases (now fixed).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by process specific code? If this is your business code then it seems clear that the separation between the two classes are that ClassA is your application service and ClassB is your business logic.

Try and untangle the classes so that your business class uses the CSV class but your CSV class doesn't use your business class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting each class create each other, use a constructor injection technique, in which each class take their dependency there, store in a private field, and use there instead of creating a new one, so that whatever starts this process creates both at once and passes to the other as needed.